# Почему pygame выдает ошибку при конвертации спрайта

Tags: python, pygame

Я делаю игру на pygame и мне нужно было конвертировать спрайт на более удобное для pygame расширение. Делал я это с помощью метода convert_alpha(). Но когда я запускал код мне выдавало такую ошибку: pygame.error: cannot convert without pygame.display initialized. Что делать?